# What is the co-kernel of the morphism of vector bundles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-surfaces

Let $X$ be a surface, and $i:C\subset X$ be a smooth curve. Let $A$ be a line bundle on $C$, and $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ on $X$.

Suppose there is a surjection: $E\longrightarrow i_*A\longrightarrow 0\\$,
then we get an exact sequence $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad0\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow i_*A\longrightarrow 0$.

Now $i_*A$ is torsion, we have $(i_*A)^*=0$. Therefore taking the dual sequence, we get

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 0\longrightarrow E^*\longrightarrow F^*\longrightarrow Q\longrightarrow 0$.

$Q$ is $\mathcal{Ext}^1(i_*A,\mathcal{O}_X)$. But what is it? I saw somewhere that it is $\mathcal{O}_C(C)\otimes A^\vee$. Is that right? How do we get it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer right away, but this seems a textbook question.

Comment: Grothendieck duality gives  isomorphisms  $R\mathcal{H}om_X(i_*A,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong i_*R\mathcal{H}om_C(A,i^!\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $i^!\mathcal{O}_X\cong \mathcal{O}_C(C))[-1]$, hence your claim. See for instance Hartshorne's "Residues and duality".

Comment: Calculate the ext group using the exact sequence, $$0\to \mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X(C)\to\mathcal{O}_C(C)\to 0,$$ and taking $\mathcal{H}om (A,*)$.

Comment: @Mohan, I am sounding stupid, but can you please elaborate? Somehow I am getting stuck repeatedly in this argument.

Comment: @poorna, Which part do you have trouble with? Are you ok with the above exact sequence? If so, when you apply the hom functor, you end up with $$0\to \mathcal{H}om(A,O_C(C))\to \mathcal{E}xt^1(A,O_X)\to\mathcal{E}xt^1(A,O_X(C))$$ exact.   Easy to check that the last map is zero and thus you get the required isomorphism.

Comment: @Mohan, thanks a lot for the prompt reply.  I got exactly the above sequence after applying $\mathcal{Hom}(A,_)$. However I am having trouble in showing that the last map is zero.

Comment: The last map is zero because both the sheaves are supported completely on $C$ and the map is just (locally) multiplication by the equation defining $C$ in $X$ and hence zero.

Comment: Sorry @Mohan I am completely bulbing. I understand that it is supported only on $C$. But on $C$, what exactly is the map?

Comment: It is induced by the map $O_X\to O_X(C)$ which is just multiplication by the equation defining $C$ in $X$. But this equation acts as zero on any sheaf supported (scheme theoretically) on $C$.